# Why are elements in a HashSet unordered?

Tags: java, hashset, unordered

What advantage is there in keeping the `Set` unordered?

Is it more efficient in space/time?

In what way is a random order easier to manage than insertion order?

Comment: I don't think this deserves to be a -5 question - it's a reasonable thing to ask and can be explained fairly concisely as the consequence of using hashing for efficient lookup (I had an answer in progress when this was closed).  Voting to re-open.

Comment: *Because* it's a hash set. That's what the words mean.

Comment: And if "Because it's a hash set" doesn't mean anything to you (e.g. you're just learning what a hash set *is*) it's a fair thing to wonder. Maybe it's not a *great* question, but it's surely not "too broad".

Comment: the question here is :- 
why a hash set is randomly accessible?
You can simply point the next node(-->) to point to the next inserted element.Suppose i have only two elements.why should the second element be made as the first element.?Whats the selective advantage?

Comment: @dimo414
Hey Dimo,
If i use hashing ,i think we 'll be putting elements in random mem locations,but pointers can point to any node to keep it ordered.
Whats the reason for incurring this extra cost of restting the next and previous pointers?

Comment: @AnkitSharma if the question is re-opened I'll try to answer it.  Please click "edit" to add additional context or details, so that it can be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Elements in a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) are ordered (*dispersed* in the Javadoc) by the `Object.hashCode()`. You can use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) if you need a `Set` that preserves insertion order.

Comment: yes,dispersing based on hash code is fine but why unordered?
The next ptr can always point to the next inserted node.
Hash Code only gives the memory location.Order we can keep by pointing curr nde to newly inserted node?why should some one bear the over head of re assigning the links in the list

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne  : got the answer,values are unordered because once hashCode is calculated,then it is followed by hascode%size of set to acccomodate it in the hash table.one liner answer.